# Open source server performance monitoring APIs

Tags: java, performance, spring, monitoring, metrics

Does anybody know / suggest an **"Open source"** performance monitoring API that can be used in Java application on JBoss?

Doing a search on StackOverflow and other resources have pointed me to Java Simon, Perf4J as some good APIs recently.

Are there any other ***Open source*** APIs ***(not tools)*** with good track record? Someone who has actually implemented those can comment on the costs involved?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What about just reading JMX-metrics? The `jboss.system:type=ServerInfo` MBean gives some information about that. You can easily read MBean-infos using twiddle and work with the returned numbers.